# TypeError: a.offset(...) is undefined when using foundation css

Tags: jquery, typeerror, zurb-foundation

i have built a site using the foundation css framework but it's throwing numerous errors saying TypeError: a.offset(...) is undefined.

It only seems to happen when I scroll down the page. Has anybody else run into this issue and more importantly has anybody found a fix to it?

Comment: see here https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/1439